# Why this Java code counts correct but prints the wrong answer?

Tags: java, arrays, sum

I have created one small Java program to check that given programs contains the sum or not. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SubarraySum{

  static void find_position(Long[] array, int size, Long find_sum){
    Long sum = 0L;
    boolean b = false;
    int c=0,d=0;
    for(int i=0;i<size; i++){
      if(sum == find_sum){
        System.out.println((c+1)+" "+(d+1));
        b = true;
        break;
      }
      sum = 0L;
      for(int j=i;j<size; j++){
        sum += array[j];
        System.out.println(i+" : "+sum+" : "+b);
        if(sum == find_sum){
          c = i; d = j;
          // System.out.println((c+1)+" "+(d+1));
          System.out.println((c+1)+" "+(d+1));
          b = true;
          // System.out.println(i+" : "+sum+" : "+b);
          // System.exit(0);
          break;
        }
        // System.out.println(i+" : "+sum+" : "+b);
        if(sum > find_sum) break;
      }
    }
    if(b == false){
      System.out.println("-1");
    }
  }

  static void takeSizeandSum(Scanner sc){
    int size = sc.nextInt();
    Long find_sum = sc.nextLong();
    Long[] array = new Long[size];
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        array[i] = sc.nextLong();
    }
    find_position(array, size, find_sum);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int TestCase = sc.nextInt();
    for(int i=0;i<TestCase;i++){
      takeSizeandSum(sc);
    }
  }
}
```

It prints wrong output in this case:

```
1
42 468
135 101 170 125 79 159 163 65 106 146 82 28 162 92 196 143 28 37 192 5 103 154 93 183 22 117 119 96 48 127 172 139 70 113 68 100 36 95 104 12 123 134
```

For this input it prints `-1` while correct answer is 38 42!

I have changed my find_position code :

```
static int find_position(int[] array, int size, int find_sum){
    int i, j;
    int sum;
    for(i =0;i<size; i++){
      sum = array[i];
      for(j=i+1;j<size;j++){
        if(sum == find_sum){
          int c = j-1;
          System.out.println(i +" "+c);
          return 1;
        }
        if(sum > find_sum || j==size){
          break;
        }
        sum += array[j];
      }
    }
    System.out.println("-1");
    return 0;
}
```

However, it still displays wrong output. Can you help me out?

Comment: I would suggest using a debugger for this.

Comment: Or alternatively, try to create a [mcve].

Comment: Don't use `Long` instead of `long` unless absolutely required. Currently your comparison might well fail.

Comment: `sum == find_sum` here you should use `equals()` like `sum.equals(find_sum)`  for `Long`

Comment: It would also help if you explain the programs logic and task a bit. Neither is trivial to understand.

Comment: @Eklavya That's, in my opinion, resolving the symptom rather than the problem.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I don't know that's only the problem or not, I just want to correct what I see wrong using comments.

Comment: i used debugger but it's not helping that's why i have posted this here.

Comment: You've still not described what your algorithm is supposed to do (the sum of **what** exactly?). I see a lot of trial and error programming here, which is generally not how you'd solve puzzles like this. You need to step back and rethink the algorithm. And use `long` instead of `Long` everywhere.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. You need to find a section within the array from two different indexes that sums up to a specific value, right?

Comment: yes that's right

Comment: Once you've got *working code* for a next problem, you might want to post it at https://codereview.stackexchange.com (do make clear you're a starting programmer). You'll get a bit more precise feedback. Do try and already format the code at the best of your ability (at least add whitespace at the correct places and lookup code practices for the particular language).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes ohk i will try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your learning experience, using `long`. I've also formatted the code, used more logical and Java-like identifiers, removed a lot of unnecessary ones, split lines, added some comments, removed the debugging code, removed the unnecessary `size` parameter (arrays carry their `.length), split the calculation and the input / output, etc.

```
public class SubarraySum {
    // generally you'd create a class with the start- and end index but
    // I'll just return a string for now
    public static String findPosition(long[] array, long sumToFind) {
        for (int startIndex = 0; startIndex < array.length; startIndex++) {
            long sum = 0;
            for (int endIndex = startIndex; endIndex < array.length; endIndex++) {
                sum += array[endIndex];
                if (sum == sumToFind) {
                    // return 1 based index
                    return String.format("(%d, %d)", startIndex + 1, endIndex + 1);
                } else if (sum > sumToFind) {
                    // end this check early, as we cannot add more values and get to a smaller sumToFind
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return "-1";
    }

    public static void takeSizeandSum(Scanner sc) {
        int size = sc.nextInt();
        long sumToFind = sc.nextLong();
        long[] array = new long[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            array[i] = sc.nextLong();
        }
        System.out.println(findPosition(array, sumToFind));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int testcases = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < testcases; i++) {
            takeSizeandSum(sc);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course, I've still left a thing out so you might still fail the tests :P